# PHP Convertir un array asociativo a un array tipo árbol

Tags: php, array

Quiero convertir un array de este tipo, en el que puede haber n filas en el array con m elementos cada una:

```
$array = array(
                0 => array(1314,1317,1320),
                1 => array(1314,1317,1321),
                2 => array(1314,1318,1320),
                3 => array(1314,1318,1321),
                4 => array(1314,1319,1320),
                5 => array(1314,1319,1321),
                6 => array(1315,1318,1321),
                7 => array(1315,1319,1321),
                8 => array(1315,1319,1322)
                );
```

A un array de tipo árbol, en el que en el ejemplo quedaría algo así:

```
$salida = array(
                1314 => array(
                            1317 => array(
                                        1320 => array(),
                                        1321 => array()
                                        ),
                            1318 => array(
                                        1320 => array(),
                                        1321 => array()
                                        ),
                            1319 => array(
                                        1320 => array(),
                                        1321 => array()
                                        )
                            ),
                1315 => array(
                            1318 => array(
                                        1321 => array()
                                        ),
                            1319 => array(
                                        1321 => array(),
                                        1322 => array()
                                        )
                            )
                );
```

He tratado funciones recursivas, añadiendo un elemento del tipo $arraysalida[$valor] = array() y luego comprobar si ya existe dicho elemento en el array y si existe añadir una hoja, pero no lo saco.

Lo más parecido que he encontrado a lo que busco, es este códijo javascript:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663096/how-to-convert-array-to-tree

Pero ni entiendo ni se traducir esta línea a PHP:

```
tree = tree[array[i]] = tree[array[i]] || {}
```

O al menos el código que he creado en PHP a partir de este código javascript, no me funciona correctamente.

¿Alguien sería tan amable de ayudarme?
¡Mil gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Checa si este fragmento de código resuelve tu problema esta basado en el js que mencionas, saludos.

Probado en php 5.4 y 5.6

```
<?php
function addToTree(&$arbol, $rama) {
    $len = count($rama);

    for($i=0; $i < $len; $i++ ) {

        if( !isset( $arbol[ $rama[$i] ] ) ) {
            $arbol[ $rama[$i] ]  = [];
        }

        $arbol = &$arbol[ $rama[$i] ];
    }   
}

function makeTree($values) 
{
    $tree = [];
    $rTree = &$tree;
    foreach( $values as $item ) {
        addToTree($rTree,$item);
    }   
    return $tree;
}

$numeric = array(
                0 => array(1314,1317,1320),
                1 => array(1314,1317,1321),
                2 => array(1314,1318,1320),
                3 => array(1314,1318,1321),
                4 => array(1314,1319,1320),
                5 => array(1314,1319,1321),
                6 => array(1315,1318,1321),
                7 => array(1315,1319,1321),
                8 => array(1315,1319,1322));

$abc = array(
                0 => array("a","b","c"),
                1 => array("a","b","d")
);

$abcTree = makeTree($abc);
$numericTree = makeTree($numeric);

echo json_encode($abcTree,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo json_encode($numericTree,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Funciona a la perfección. Ahora me toca ver bien cómo lo has hecho para aprender de ello. ¡Mil gracias!

He votado tu respuesta, pero no tengo nivel para que se visualice.

Comment: Al final de cada iteracion $arbol referencia (apunta) al siguiente nodo ya sea uno vació (que se acabamos de crear) o al que ya existe en ese indice. Resumiendo con cada iteracion se baja un nivel en el árbol.

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma de hacerlo con una función recursiva:

```
<?php

function agregarNodos($rama, &$arbol) {
    $key = current($rama);

    if($key !== false) {
        if(! array_key_exists($key, $arbol)) {
            $arbol[$key] = array();
        }

        next($rama);

        agregarNodos($rama, $arbol[$key]);
    }
}

$arbol = array();

foreach($array as $rama) {
    agregarNodos($rama, $arbol);
}
?>
```

Usando dos funciones recursivas:

```
<?php

function agregarNodos($rama, &$arbol) {
    $nodo = current($rama);

    if($nodo !== false) {
        if(! array_key_exists($nodo, $arbol)) {
            $arbol[$nodo] = array();
        }

        next($rama);

        agregarNodos($rama, $arbol[$nodo]);
    }
}

function agregarRamas($ramas, &$arbol) {
    $rama = current($ramas);

    if($rama !== false) {
        agregarNodos($rama, $arbol);

        next($ramas);

        agregarRamas($ramas, $arbol);
    }
}

$arbol = array();

agregarRamas($array, $arbol);

?>
```